# Adding a breakpoint in ecliipse on read/write to a particular [IP Address]:port

Tags: java, sockets, nio, datagram

There are many processes that will write to some channels.Is there a way to add a breakpoint whenever read/write happens on a particular `[IP address]:port` or any `[IP address]:port`.

Adding a watchpoint on the channel variable is not useful because all processes will have different variables.

How can I add a breakpoint when DatagramChannel's read/write or send/recieve is called from any part of the code?
Or is there a better way?

Comment: Conditional breakpoints perhaps: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F